# GCP Dataflow custom template creation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create a custom template in dataflow, so that I can use a DAG from composer to run on a set frequency. I have understood that I need to deploy my Dataflow template first, and then the DAG.

I have used this example - [https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#:~:text=The%20following%20example%20shows%20how%20to%20stage%20a%20template%20file%3A](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#:%7E:text=The%20following%20example%20shows%20how%20to%20stage%20a%20template%20file%3A)

My code:

```
- python3 -m job.process_file \ 
--runner DataflowRunner \
--project project \ 
--staging_location gs://bucketforjob/staging \ 
--temp_location gs://bucketforjob/temp \ 
--template_location gs://bucketfordataflow/templates/df_job_template.py \
--region eu-west2 \--output_bucket gs://cleanfilebucket \
--output_name file_clean \
--input gs://rawfilebucket/file_raw.csv
```

The issue I am having is, it just trys to run the pipeline (the input file doesn't exist in the bucket yet, and I don't want it to randomly process it by putting it in there), so it fails saying that file_raw.csv doesn't exist in bucket. how do I get it just to create/compile the pipeline as a template in the template folder for me to call on with my dag?

This is really confusing me, and there seems to be little guidance out there from what I could find... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would like to separate commands for a template creation from the job execution.

[An example on a page you provided](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#python), depicts necessary parameters...

> python -m examples.mymodule 
> --runner DataflowRunner 
> --project PROJECT_ID 
> --staging_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/staging 
> --temp_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/temp 
> --template_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/templates/TEMPLATE_NAME 
> --region REGION

where `examples.mymodule` - is the source code (as I understand), and `--template_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/templates/TEMPLATE_NAME` - is the place, where the result template is to be stored.

In order to execute the job, you might like to run a command according to the [Running classic templates using gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates#using-gcloud) documentation example...

> gcloud dataflow jobs run JOB_NAME 
> --gcs-location gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/templates/MyTemplate 
> --parameters inputFile=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/input/my_input.txt,outputFile=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/output/my_output

Or, in your case, you probably would like to start the job [Using the REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates#using-the-rest-api)

In any case - don't forget about relevant IAM roles and permissions for service accounts, under which the job is to run.

Comment: Thank you - so is it fair to say with the python command had I actually let it process the file (by providing it in the raw bucket) it would have created a template on the back of it in the template location? For reuse in future?

Comment: Yes, I think you understand it correctly. 2 steps - create a template in advance (using the python command to process the source code of the 'job') and then, in the future, run job(s) - as many times, as you need.